# How to search all string in MySql that start with a number?

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I want to run a mysql query to give me all available results that start with a number.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE number + '%'
```

I tried using

```
LIKE REGEXP '^[0-9]
```

but it is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1315/1)

Comment: Just barely faster than me!

Comment: This is the correct answer. It return the string that start with a number

Comment: @Mike -- Glad we could help!  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your RegExp is wrong, and the way you are using the REGEXP operator is wrong.  Your code should be

```
WHERE username REGEXP '^[0-9].*'
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a8b/1)

Edit: I'm wrong about the RegEx portion.  I didn't realize you don't need the .*

Comment: Thank you for your help but this return any string that contains a number. @sgeddes got it right :)  Thanks